# New array allocations

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

So i have this class called point, just to log to the console everytime an object gets constructed and destroyed. And i did the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct point{
    point() {
        std::cout << "ctor\n";
    }
    ~point() {
        std::cout << "dtor\n";
    }
};
    int main(){
    int x = 3;
    point* ptr = new point[x]{point()};
    delete[] ptr;
}
```

```
ctor
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

This ended up calling the constructor just once, and the destructor 3 times, why? I know that this is bad, probably ub, but i would like to understand why. This other allocations give me the "expected" output:

```cpp
int x = 3;
constexpr int y = 3;
point* ptr1 = new point[3];
point* ptr2 = new point[x];
point* ptr3 = new point[y]{point()};
```

```
ctor
ctor
ctor
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

Im using visual studio 19 latest version.

Comment: It would help to see `point`'s constructors, so we can know how you know how many constructors are being called.

Comment: [Works](http://cpp.sh/5a2yd) for me

Comment: [Reproduced](https://rextester.com/VXKSB71226) on ms vc++. Works as expected on GCC.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new point[x]{point(),point(),point()}` instead?

Comment: AFAIK it should call the default constructor on the other members. As it would if x was a compile-time constant.

Comment: Posting a [mcve] compilable, minimal source code including `int main()` and all the relevant `include` would help others reproduce the problem and save others from applying same code fixes. Could you please edit and fix the code snipped and post the execution output you are getting?

Comment: @vini The elements without explicit array initializer should be default initialized. Ie. the first element is copy-initialized, the others should call `point()` anyway. Ie. `point ptr[3] = {point()};` outputs ctor 3 times.

Comment: @KamilCuk I dont think the first element is copy-constructed, i think the compiler uses copy elision there.

Comment: Since it works as expected on GCC and Clang, I smell a MSVC bug.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, but copy-initialization from a prvalue doesn't actually call the copy constructor in C++17.

Comment: @KamilCuk Well yes but since "point()" is a rvalue, its elegible for copy elision, also "point", when provided with a copy-ctor and move-ctor, still calls the default ctor.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Just tested on compiler explorer with gcc, works as expected, i think is safe to say that is a MCVS bug

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your problem. On my machine, the constructor is called three times as expected. (Edit: @interjay saw that before me. Seems like a bug in vc++ then.)

Comment: wow it's true, MSVS Community 2019: https://i.ibb.co/Jc5N5Qy/asdd.jpg

Comment: If you add a copy-constructor (which outputs something) does it change the program output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a compiler bug.

By using operator new without a constant defined type size MSVC compiler will call the class object constructor and destructor as many times as explicitly specified at initializer list and/or array size.

```
#include <iostream>

struct point {
    point() {
        std::cout << "ctor\n";
    }
    ~point() {
        std::cout << "dtor\n";
    }
};
int main() {
    int x = 3;
    point* ptr = new point[x]{point()};
    delete[] ptr;
}
```

As stated will call as *explicitly specified* `point` ctor once.

This can be asserted by: `point* ptr = new point[x]{point(), point()};`

- MSVC Output: `ctor ctor dtor dtor dtor`.
- GCC: `ctor ctor ctor dtor dtor dtor` (which should be guaranteed)

And even a throwable array out of bound exception UB: `point* ptr = new point[x]{point(), point(), point(), point(), point() };` follows the behavior.

- MSVC Output: `ctor ctor ctor ctor ctor dtor dtor dtor`.
- GCC: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'`

Too many initializers is correctly detected if the defined size is constant. i.e `const int x = 3` or `constexpr int x = 3`

Answer (score 0):

This might not give you any direct answer, but just presenting some observations.

As @interjay has commented, we could see that there is a difference between how the same piece of code runs in VC++ and other popular compilers. I didn't see any deviation from standards were mentioned in MSDN, and infact VC++ do support for list and other iniliazilers following [the standards in VS2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/initializers?view=vs-2019).

Now while playing with different notations of rewriting the same thing, what I observed was something interesting.

Verifying what is documented in MSDN I see that for the following notation,

```
point* ptr = new point[x]{};
```

Output is as expected, and functionally it is consistent across different compilers.

```
ctor
ctor
ctor
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

Also with the following stack based array allocation,

```
 point ptr[3] = {point()};
```

gets us

```
ctor
ctor
ctor
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

So far everything looks good and the results matches with other compilers, not until we call the following code:

```
point* ptr = new point[x]{point()};
```

Just coming with best of what I understand from this is that this could be a implementation glitch in VC++.

As you call **new** operator along with constructor initialization inside the braces, may be for VC++ this is not a  recommended usage, and internally it falls back to some custom initialization handler where it is expected to call constructors when explicitly assigned for each indices, while rest everything else is just allocated with uninitialized memory (no constructor gets called). This is a clear undefined behavior (UB).

While, in the couple of examples that I have shown earlier, it seems like  (looking at the call stack in Windbg, I could be entirely wrong with this) internally VC++ at the runtime calls something similar to vector constructor initializer which calls the default constructor (only) iteratively for all indices.

Again this can be verifies using following piece of code, where calling a constructor overload

```
 point(int i) {
            std::cout << "ctor "<<i<<"\n";
        }
```

from

```
point ptr[3] = {point(10)}; //not a default constructor
```

spits out:

```
ctor 10
ctor
ctor
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

This is weird and an abnormal behavior, which is nothing new in VC++. What I can suggest is that try using the following notation to get consistant result in cross different compilers:

```
point* ptr = new point[x]{};
```

Comment: Your last example gave the expected result - one call to the int constructor and two default constructors. Nothing weird and abnormal about it. I also don't understand what you mean by "non-standard usage" and "clear undefined behavior", as nothing like that exists here.

Comment: @interjay what is here worth observing is `point* ptr = new point[x]{point()};` vs `point* ptr = new point[x]{};`. I haven't said `point* ptr = new point[x]{};` is weird, but this is `point* ptr = new point[x]{point()};`. By non-standard usage, I mean if this `point* ptr = new point[x]{point()};` is recommended way of array initialization ot not.

Answer (score -1):

> This ended up calling the constructor just once, and the destructor 3 times, why?

You need to log the copy and move constructors as well:

```
#include <iostream>

struct point{
    point() {
        std::cout << "default ctor\n";
    }
    point(const point &) {
        std::cout << "copy ctor\n";
    }
    point(point &&) {
        std::cout << "move ctor\n";
    }
    ~point() {
        std::cout << "dtor\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: While probably true, as written, it's unclear how it's relevant to the question.

Comment: Its relevant because the OP's code could be invoking constructors that are not being logged. That is one of the common causes when people run into issues where more destructor calls are logged than constructor calls.

Comment: But this isn't the issue here, as the default constructor should be called 3 times. Besides, this method won't always work due to copy elision.

Comment: @interjay whether elision is used or not, the number of constructor calls has to match the number of destructor calls

Comment: You need to explain that in your answer, though. Otherwise, it looks like you recommended changes without an explanation.